# How do you pronounce the letter S in disent or lisent?

Tags: prononciation, orthographe

I began to study French. I think it is a pretty good language. However, I am confused about some special pronunciation rules. E. g., pronunciation of S in words "disent" and "lisent". Does it sounds [s] or [z]? (I think it can be [z], because it is between two vowels even if E is silent. But I'm not sure.)

Comment: The "between two vowels" clue is indeed a good one. *aise*, *philosophe*, *ose*, *peser*, *base*, etc. all follow this rule. Note that between two vowels across two words doesn't count: *la soupe* [s]. Unless it is due to liaison: *les oiseaux* [lez].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 's' is pronounced [z] in these cases because it is between two vowels but you should be careful because there are a few exceptions.

They are relatively easy to spot if you are able to detect that the word is a concatenation of a prefix (or another word) and a word that starts with an 's', e.g.:

- *parasol*
- *vraisemblable*
- *désolidariser* (but *désolé* = [dezɔle])
- *dysenterie* (but *dysurie*, an exception in the exceptions…)
- *asocial*
- *resalir*

Note that the word *abasourdi* is very often mispronounced by native French speakers with an [s] while it must be pronounced with a [z].

Answer (score 1):

In both words, the *s* sounds like [z].